# Can the word God be colloquially replaced with f***?

Tags: word-usage, slang

I stumbled across these lyrics from "Enter Shikari - The Last Garrison":

> Head's up and thank fuck you're still alive!

It sounds like that there was "God" replaced with "fuck". It even sounds surprisingly similar. Another example I often hear is:

> For fuck's sake

which also obviously replaces "God" with "fuck".

This made me wonder if it is really a common slang thing to replace "God" with "fuck"?

Comment: It is certainly true that both words have been and are extensively used as intensifiers. And the important thing about intensifiers is that they must have shock quality. Their underlying meanings are of little relevance. What counts is that they provide emphasis and they stir people to listen. They are also a form of violence, in that they can wound the sort of people who are likely to be offended by their use.

Comment: There are not a lot of words that **can't** be replaced with 'fuck'. In the case of 'god', there are still a lot of religious folk that are offended whenever their deity's name is used in vein. Replacing 'god' with 'fuck' turns it into a regular vulgarity by removing the religious aspect.

Comment: Potentially offensive language is bowdlerized in question titles. Please see Meta discussion http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7704/what-is-the-policy-for-question-titles-containing-vulgar-words As for the capitalization of *God* that was suggested by a previous editor, I'm not sure I fully agree with the choice but presumably the OP is referring to the Christian god, and not just any deity.

Comment: You can read about **expletives** if you're interested in this subject.

Comment: This just made me think up my new favourite swear word "fuckdamnit":  eg "Aaargh fuckdamnit I've been blocked out of my fuckdamn mobile banking app again!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no specific relationship between the two words. Those are just examples of how *fuck* can be substituted for practically any word—for shock value, or to express anger or frustration. Your examples are just phrases where "God" would normally be used.

Comment: Yes. It could be “for Pete’s sake” or any other thing.

Comment: Yeah, I've known people who use "fuck" or "fucking" about every third word.  They think it makes them seem cool, but it only makes them tedious.

Answer (score 2):

The wiktionary web site lists the following [synonyms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for_fuck%27s_sake) for the phrase "for fuck's sake"

> for goodness sake
>
> for mercy's sake
>
> for pity's sake
>
> for God's sake
>
> for Pete's sake
>
> for Christ's sake

The Oxford dictionary has [fuck](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fuck),  used as an  exclamation,

> Used alone or as a noun or verb in various phrases to express annoyance, contempt or impatience

In the case of

> Thank fuck you're still alive

the underlying sentiment is to thank God, but the speaker avoids saying God because he or the person he is speaking to may not believe in Him or that He was responsible for the preservation of life.

He could say

> Thank your lucky stars

but again they may not believe in astrology.

By using the word fuck rather than God, your lucky stars, Lady Luck, the laws of science, or any similar expressions, the speaker avoids any overtly religious or philosophical implications about the reason the person is still alive.

The whole realm of theology, philosophy and science, whoever or whatever has kept the person alive, is conjured up by the simple word "fuck", without attempting to articulate a belief or theory about what "fuck" may be.

In the phrase

> for fuck's sake

something similar is meant, but has the advantage of carrying an emphatic meaning. There may be also a reluctance to use the word God, for example, to avoid any suggestion of blasphemy.

> For God's sake, get me another beer.

could seem somewhat blasphemous. "Fuck" avoids any implication that fetching the beer is  a religious duty.

One would not, of course, substitute "fuck" for "God" in Church, or when having tea with the vicar.